# bash variables from nested for loops in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I want to simply use the two for loop variables in my awk code but I can't. Please help or guide me in the right direction.

```
for i in {30,60,100}; 
do 
   for j in {7,8}; 
   do 
       awk -v x=$i -v y=$j '{if ($NF <=x) print $0}' S_$i.txt > S_$i_$j.txt;
   done;
done
```

This was the error I received.

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file S_.txt for reading (No such file or directory). I saw this error.
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Dervis

Comment: what is the error in your code? it looks ok!

Comment: what do you mean by `'but I can't'`? do you receive an error message? do you get the wrong results (and if so, what are the 'wrong' results vs the expected results)? while you're passing in 2x variables, it doesn't appear the `awk` script is using the `y=$j` variable ... is that expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`S_$i_$j.txt` is trying to access a variable named `$i_`. Use `S_${i}_${j}.txt` instead but also always quote your shell variables so it should really be:

```
awk -v x="$i" -v y="$j" '{if ($NF <= x) print $0}' "S_${i}.txt" > "S_${i}_${j}.txt"
```

or more awkishly:

```
awk -v x="$i" -v y="$j" '$NF <= x' "S_${i}.txt" > "S_${i}_${j}.txt"
```

and note that you never use `y` inside your awk script so it could just be:

```
awk -v x="$i" '$NF <= x' "S_${i}.txt" > "S_${i}_${j}.txt"
```

but then it's not clear why you'd want to create 2 copies of your output with each inner loop.

Whatever you're doing, though, could almost certainly be done much faster with a single call to awk than calling it multiple times within shell loops!

The problem you asked about has absolutely nothing to do with `for loop variables in my awk code` btw, it's all shell fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am planning on using y as a condition but I haven't yet decided yet, that's why y is there. Sorry about the confusion. I did try the ${i} and ${j} way and it worked. However, the bottom code also works. Sorry about my question being not clear about bash and awk. Thanks again for the solutions, they are very helpful.

Comment: The way you posted in your answer is bad because while it gets you past the specific failure you were seeing it still exposes variables to the shell for globbing, filename expansion, etc. One of the most fundamental things to learn in shell programming is to always quote your shell variables as I'm doing in my answer - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: Ok I prefer your answer cause I want to do the robust way of shell programming. Thanks for helping me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your quick response.
However, I tried the following and it worked:

```
for i in {30,60,100}; 
    do 
     for j in {7,8}; 
      do 
       awk -v x=$i -v y=$j '{if ($NF <=x) print $0}' "S_"$j".txt" > "S_"$j"_"$i".txt";
      done;
    done;
```

Additionally, I realized that S_30.txt didn't exist. So when I changed it to "S_"$j".txt" it worked fine. My bad on that one.

Comment: Don't do that - you're specifically **excluding** the parts of each symbol that you need to **include** in the quotes - the shell variables. Also - put the error message you need help with in your question, not in an answer.

Comment: I realized that S_30.txt didn't exist. So when I changed it to "S_"$j".txt" it worked fine. My bad on that one.

Comment: Don't use `for i in {30,60,100}` but `for i in 30 60 100`, there is no valid reason to use Bash specific brace expression here. Also `for ...; do` either separate statements with semicolon `;` either with a new line, but not both. See: https://shellcheck.net/ recommendations on your code.